# Access/mount the partitions inside an LVM2-based disk of a shut-down KVM guest?

Tags: mount, lvm, kvm-virtualization

On the KVM host how can I mount the volumes on the disk of a KVM guest that has been shut down, if the disk was configured to be an LVM2-based volume?

The KVM guest was installed using the normal setup DVD of 12.04 and the partitions created are one for `/` and one for swap. Nothing special. No nested LVM2 volumes or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
kpartx -a /var/lib/libvirt/images/guest1.img
# vgscan
Reading all physical volumes . This may take a while...
Found volume group "ubuntu" using metadata type lvm2
# vgchange -ay ubuntu
2 logical volumes in volume group ubuntu now active.
```

Then you will have the guest volumes in /dev/mapper/ which you can mount.

Comment: thanks, you got my question wrong, I think. I know how to do this for images in the form of a file. Trouble is, that KVM uses an LVM2 *volume* as the disk for the guest. And inside that LVM2 volume would be the structure for the disk the guest sees. So the outer volume is LVM2, the inner isn't anything with LVM2 at all.

Comment: I use that. Simple instead of `/var/lib/libvirt/images/guest1.img` use `/dev/mapper/vghost--volumename`

Comment: alright, will give it a try and accept or ask back.